# Using PHP to copy files from a ScreenOS device

Tags: php, security, scp

I am making a script to backup configs for firewalls. One thing I want to do is `scp` files from ScreenOS devices, but I get a blank line from the CLI.

What I need to do in build this functionality into an already existing web interface, so I need to be able to run this command from within PHP.

I have looked at `shell_exec`, `system`, etc, but im haivng issues at the CLI level running the commands.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When i try to run the command, nothing happens. It does NOT show an error code, but shows a new line with a `$` (prompt). Looks like it was successful, but no new file is made locally.

Comment: So this question is not really programming related? You are having problem with scp, even in the terminal? We can migrate your question to http://unix.stackexchange.com/ if you'd like

Comment: It was more of, we have an issue, can we solve it programatically.. But, six answered it and it's working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been in the field for years. This is actually a bug with ScreenOS devices that are version 6.5 or less.

There is an article, [Gotcha - SCP Returns To Prompt](http://www.highonphp.com/scp-returns-to-prompt), which documents this bug and walks you through configuring a separate install of OpenSSH which includes the SCP fix to support older ScreenOS devices.

As for your web interface, once you get this bug fixed, map your `shell_exec` command to this new `scp` binary, and you will be all set.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into this, we are on 6.3.0, so this may be the reason. Are there any ways to tell for sure if this is the problem?

Comment: Yes, look in the log on the screenos device, see if you see an scp failure references file ` -- -f :ns_config_sys` not found or alike..